# Dynamic security rules for "endless" children in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Hey so I have this Firebase layout where I have files and every file can have children and all the children can have children, etc. How would I set up my security rules to dynamically work for the children (32 max if I'm remembering it correctly?). It kind of has to work with different read/write permissions depending on the user etc.

This is how it would work in a perfect world:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
                "files": {
                    "$file": {
                        // permissions ...
                        "children": {
                            "$file": {
                                // permissions ...
                                "children": {
                                    // etc ...
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Firebase supports this. They advocate flat data structures as opposed to deep nesting, so you may need to re-think your structure.

Comment: @AnidMonsur Do you have an idea on how I could re-structure? Maybe an external database handling the file's existence and then Firebase for for the content?